# How to include a short message in email body, which has a page of workbook included?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling to include a short message in email body, which has a page of workbook included. I can't find the reason. It's working perfect, but I can't add a message before the table. Any help, please? Thank you:)

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Sheet20.UsedRange
'You can also use a sheet name
'Set rng = Sheets("Sheet20").UsedRange

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Hi there"

On Error Resume Next

msg = "<body style = 'font-family:Trebuchet;'>" & "Good morning," & "<br><br>" & "<p style ='color: Red;'> Please see attached the IC225 daily casualty list. </p>"
msg = msg & "<h3>Summary for " & dr.Shapes("DR_TITLE").TextFrame.Characters.Text & "</h3>"



With OutMail
    .To = "julia.naydenova@lner.co.uk"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Investigation Request"
    .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.HTMLBody = msg & "<br>" & RangetoHTML(rng)
```